# Htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following URL:

```
 index.php?pag=jobs_desc&idJob=120&job=Java-Developer
```

I need something like this:

```
 /jobs_desc/Java-Developer/120
```

with .htaccess.

How can I write the rule?

Comment: Please read this first: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you tried /anything/ yet? The apache mod rewrite page has examples that do exactly this kind of simple redirect?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ index.php?pag=$1&idJob=$3&job=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?pag=$1&idJob=$3&job=$2 [L]
```

[L] making it last rule.